# Typescript type for a file converted to binary

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-types

I need to send a file uploaded by user in the body of my post request. I have converted file into binary form. What will be the type for this file. Currently I'm using string.

```
export interface PostRequestPayload {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  content: string;
  file?: string ; //what will be the type for this
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that reads the file?

Comment: How about `File`, `Blob` or `ArrayBuffer`?